# How to write to a array in JSON file without replacing the entire file

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, database, filesystems

Using the `fs` module. I am trying to append an array to a json file. At this point I am trying to avoid databases. Will JSON do what I need it to do or should I try a different way of handeling data?

What I have tried:

```
let homeFile_JsData = {
id: id,
title: title,
author: user
}
let homeFile_data = JSON.stringify(homeFile_JsData);
fs.writeFileSync("json/home.json", homeFile_data, "UTF-8",{'flags': 'a+'});
```

Output:

```
{"id":"2", "title":"2nd_title", "authour":"2nd_me"}
```

But I would like it to look like:

```
"array" [
{"id":"1", "title":"1st_title", "authour":"1st_me"},
{"id":"2", "title":"2nd_title", "authour":"2nd_me"}
]
```

Comment: You can't.  JSON (a plain text format) is not a format that supports insertion of new data without rewriting most of the data.  Unless the new JSON data was exactly the same number of text bytes as the original text, you would have to at least rewrite everything after the insertion point in the file.

Comment: To efficiently insert data without rewriting lots of the data, you need a different structure for the data (such as a database, or adding rows onto a CSV file) that more directly supports modification on disk storage.

Comment: That makes more sense. I will look in to CSV and see if it solves my problem!

Comment: You can append CSV rows using `fs.appendFileSync()`.

Comment: Thanks! I will look in to that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add a new row of data, then JSON isn't really the right format.  It is not design for incremental updates and thus you generally have to read the entire JSON, parse it into a Javascript object, modify the Javascript object, convert back to JSON, then write the entire file of JSON.

If you are just adding a new element to the end of an array at the end of the JSON, you could (very carefully) find a way to overwrite just the right amount of JSON to add onto the end of it, but that's not really a good way to do things as, small changes in the structure could break the code.

On the other hand, for just adding a new row of data, the CSV text format can do that fairly easily as each line in the file represents a record and you can just add new lines of data onto the end of the file with `fs.appendfileSync()` at any time.  You would then have to get a parser for the CSV data since nodejs doesn't have a CSV parser built in, but there are numerous modules that can do that on NPM or you could even write your own as CSV isn't difficult to parse.

Of course, a more scalable solution would involve using a simple database that lets you incrementally modify, add or delete any of the data and the database handles the disk storage of the data entirely for you.  It, of course, also provides all sorts of other features such as queries and concurrency protection, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go with your solution... CSV worked well. I did decide to do some playing around in a sandbox and this also worked for me:

```
let datares = fs.readFileSync('user-mgm/users.json');
let data = JSON.parse(datares); 
var arr = data.array 
const new_thing = {id: id_string, data: data_string}

arr.push(new_thing)

var new_Js = {
  non_array: "HELLO WORLD",
  array: arr
}
let string_js = JSON.stringify(new_Js);
  fs.writeFileSync('file.json', string_js, "UTF-8",{'flags': 'a'});
}
```

Looking at this, a database would be a good idea.